# Porting new.module() to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

How would I implement this in Python3:

```
def import_code(code, name, add_to_sys_modules=False):
    module = new.module(name)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    do_bookkeeping(module)
    exec(code in module.__dict__)

    return module
```

Seems like neither `__import__` nor `importlib` actually *return* the module that can be used for bookkeeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` module has been removed from Python 3. You can use [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.ModuleType) instead, in both Python 2 and 3.

You have your `exec()` call wrong; it should be:

```
exec(code, module.__dict__)
```

You are trying to execute the `False` result from the `code in module.__dict__` expression instead. Using `exec()` as a function also works in Python 2, so the following works across the major versions:

```
import types

def import_code(code, name, add_to_sys_modules=False):
    module = types.ModuleType(name)
    if add_to_sys_modules:
        sys.modules[name] = module
    do_bookkeeping(module)
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
    return module
```

Comment: That's just error made in typing the question in, the actual question is the `new` module being gone and no way to do `new.module(name)`. Will revise my question